# C# Automatically linking strings to properties using the string value

Tags: c#, .net

This might be a stupid one but I'll shoot it out there.

For example let's say I have a model class:

```
public class PermissionModel
{
    public bool AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool AppName_Home_Product_ConfirmButton_Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following list of strings:

```
"AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled_true"
"AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled_false"
```

I want to automatically populate the model properties with true/false without having to use if statements as in the following example:

```
if (aString.Contains("AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled"))
{       
    PermissionModel.AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(AString.Substring(AString.IndexOf("Enabled_") + 8));
}
```

Any ideas or is this crazy?  I just want to avoid a bunch of if statements to populate the model and make it more re-usable.

Comment: Where would these strings come from? I could suggest using configuration sections (appwide) or profile for individuals.

Comment: you can do this using reflection but you are certainly using an odd format where you join fieldname and it's value into one string. Looks to me you are asking for trouble that way. If anything then at the very least split it into something like AppName_Home_Product_SaveButton_Enabled,true so you can split name and value somewhat reliable. Or one step better create the list of values as a serialized settings object of some sort.

Comment: To Keni: The values will be coming from a database. It's a list of permissions.  To add more background, this is an attempt to map permissions for a particular user to a permission model that will be used by a ASP.NET MVC view to limit access to certain view objects/widgets.

Comment: To Eddy:  Adding a ',' makes sense.  Can you provide more information regarding the serialized settings object?  I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via reflection

```
const string delimiter = "_Enabled";
foreach (string data in aString) {
  int index = data.IndexOf(delimiter);
  if (index >= 0) {

    // Get the name and value out of the data string 
    string name = data.Substring(0, index + delimiter.Length);
    bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(data.Substring(index + delimiter.Length + 1));

    // Find the property with the specified name and change the value
    PropertyInfo  property = GetType().GetProperty(name);
    if (property != null) {
      property.SetValue(this, value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: However... keep in mind that reflection is slow compared to compiled `if` statements.

Comment: @Eric indeed. I believe this solution has an advantage in maintainability as you have one less item to keep in sync. Yet the idea of keeping the string names and properties names in sync scares me as well. It seems like a code generation strategy would be preferable here.

Comment: @JaredPar  This might be too big of a question to answer here but what would a code generation strategy entail.  I wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: @user740952 it is a bit hard to elaborate here. But the basic strategy is use a non-code format such as XML to define all of your properties.  Then have a tool which generates a partial class that both defines the properties and generates the `if` statement chain to set them based on the string.  Adding new properties entails editing the XML file, re-running your tool and then building.

Comment: @user740952 one solution you may want to look into is T4 templates. They integrate nicely with Visual Studio and while I don't have a lot of experience with them, they do provide nice code gen solutions for a variety of scenarios. Any questions you have about them will be quickly answered by someone on this site :)